# Как на Python написать файл exe

Tags: python, exe

Мне нужно чтобы файл .py создавал исполняемые файлы .exe на питоне как-то так:

```
k = open('blabla.exe','w')
k.write('print(\'Hello\')')
k.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, рекомендую начать с того, что разобраться в базовых понятиях. А именно - "исполняемый файл != exe-файл". С учетом этого, написанный вами текст вполне себе корректно создает файл с расширением "exe" (впрочем - и с любым другим), но это будет не исполняемый файл.

Во-вторых, если вы хотите создать именно исполнимый файл, это значит, что надо выполнить компиляцию текста, который вы создадите. Т.е. вы пишете программу (на каком, кстати, языке? ),  и передаете ее на вход компилятора, который вызываете из своего скрипта, который почему-то не просто создает исполнимый файл, а возвращает его в вызвавшую его программу, что-бы она уже записала ее в какой-то файл. Вам не кажется, что это мягко говоря сложновато и нелогично. Может, лучше хорошенько еще раз продумать и модифицировать логику своей программы?

Если-же вам надо просто откомпилировать файл, написанный на Python, и создать в результате исполнимый файл, то вот, можете ознакомиться :

https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html

http://www.py2exe.org/

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

https://golos.io/ru--programmirovanie/@pythono/python-kompilyaciya-skriptov-v-exe-fail

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб файл .exe заработал,нельзя просто какой то текст ввести,можно скомпилировать python код в exe при помощи pyinstaller,для начала нужно его скачать,при помощи pip,в cmd пишем pip install pyinstaller,а потом в том же cmd пишем pyinstaller --onefile ваш_.py_файл